# Background Image with 100% height: Need to fill page

Tags: css, image, background

I have a small .png file that repeats to form a background image. I need to set the `body` height of my page to 100% in order to use min-height property on my content wrapper. However, trying to use the background-image in conjunction with `height:100%` results in the image getting cut off when the page is scrolled. See picture to elaborate what I mean:

Background on top
[image]
But when scrolling it is cut off

How do I get the background image to repeat over the whole page, even after the user scrolls down? Here is the css:

```
body {  
    background-color:#9AAEBF; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
}

html:after {
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/img/background.png');    
    opacity:0.4;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Thanks for your ideas.

---

EDIT:

This is the image i need repeated:

[image: Image Repeated]

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Nick_B/x2h3g/

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're attaching the background with the CSS-Pseudo-Selector `:after`? That will not work on many older browsers. Also i'm wondering why it's absutely positioned. I'd simply put the background-img in the body tag or even your first container div on the page.

Comment: I dont care about old browsers. I am using `after` because that is how you can use opacity on `html` element without affecting child elements. See: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
html:after {
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/img/background.png');    
    background-repeat:repeat;
    opacity:0.4;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I think the image is already being repeated from what the question text reads.

Comment: Yes that true @Philzen. This is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: if you want it make a background image in your whole page just simple add in the body `body {
    background-image: url('http://www.example.com/img/background.png');    
    background-repeat:repeat;
}`

Comment: Doesnt work in my version of chrome or firefox. Thanks for the idea however.

Comment: welcome maybe if you can show a fiddle so we can play on maybe it big help

Comment: Added a fiddle above. Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

**Now used** to `background-size`

As like this

```
body {  
    background-color:#9AAEBF; 
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height:100%;
}

html:after {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuzZU.png'); 
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.4;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**[Demo Full page](http://jsfiddle.net/YkhkF/embedded/result/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YkhkF/1/)**

Comment: This doesnt work. See the above fiddle to help with any ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve your desired result through give the `backgroun-size:100%` in your `html:after`

**CSS**

```
html:after {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuzZU.png'); 
    background-size:100%;
    opacity:0.4;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Because the image is small and repeated. See the above fiddle. Thanks!