# Need background image to fill screen to bottom even when scrolling

Tags: html, css, background

This seems like a basic question but I can't find an answer anywhere...

I have a container `div` with a background image. It contains a content `div` with text that expands the `divs` beyond the browser's viewable area.

The image is displayed at 100% height but when scrolling down to show the text beyond the screen's bottom, the image will scroll up and no longer fill to the bottom of the scrolled screen - with or without `repeat` being set.

A jsfiddle [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/mseifert/zy68y1hv/3/). Just load the page and scroll the output up to see the image end with text continuing.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195163/background-image-with-100-height-need-to-fill-page). But it does not have an accepted answer and doesn't apply as it is using `html:after`.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**UPDATE**
I've updated the jsfiddle. The layout was a bit more complex and I was trying to avoid going there. It involves two `divs` side by side and they were being held in place by a `float: left`. Without the `float: left`, the background plays nice but the divs won't sit side by side. Any ideas?

**UPDATE2**
The solution in addition to removing `height:100%` is to add the following: **HTML**

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>  <!-- keeps page-container-div expanding with content so border is correct-->
```

HTML (orig)

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="main-nav-vert">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    </div>
    <div class="main-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {height:100%}
body {
    background:rgb(255,243,230);
}
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width:978px; 
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%; 
    background:rgb(240,240,240) url(http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/lady-sprite.jpg) repeat top center; 
}

.main-content {
    max-width:808px; 
    width: auto;
    margin-left:145px;
    padding:0 9px 0 9px;
    background: rgb(240,240,240);
    overflow:visible !important;
}
.main-nav-vert {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width:145px; 
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `height: 100%` from the `.page-container`.

```
html, body {
    height:100%
}
.page-container {
    position: relative;
    max-width:978px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height:100%;
    background:rgb(240, 240, 240) url(http://www.waldorfteacherresources.com/img/lady-sprite.jpg) repeat;
}
.main-content {
    width: auto;
    background: transparent;
    overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: Ah... My example is simplified and explains why when I tried removing `height:100%` it didn't fix it. There is also `float: left` with the .page-container and it was this that was preventing the filling as well. Do you know why a `float: left` would cause this behavior?

Comment: I've update the jsfiddle (and the question above to match). The issue is that there are two `divs` inside the `page-container` which need to stay side by side. I use `float: left` to accomplish this but it breaks the background. Thanks for taking a look at it.

Comment: The final solution was to add `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`  See the example for where it was needed. I also update the jsfiddle. This code keeps the page-container-div expanding with content. However, since you answer was half the problem, I marked it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to set the position to fixed.

```
.page-container {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: `position: fixed;` will prevent all vertical scrolling - so doesn't fix it.

Comment: Apply the background css styles to a child div instead. <div class="page-container"><div class="bg"></div></div>

Comment: Unfortunately there are two divs side by side within the page-container - so neither one can have the background. I've re-written the question and the jsfiddle to reflect this. Thanks for looking.